# Building a weighted histogram using two binary files

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have two binary files that I need to iterate through simultaneously so that the value yielded in one file corresponds correctly (same location) to the value yielded in the other. I'm sorting values into histogram bins and the value from one file corresponds to the weight of the value from the other file.

I tried the following syntax:

```
import numpy as np
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

low = np.inf
high = -np.inf

struct_fmt = 'f'
struct_len = struct.calcsize(struct_fmt)
struct_unpack = struct.Struct(struct_fmt).unpack_from

file = "/projects/current/real-core-snaps/core4_256_velx_0009.bin"
file2 = "/projects/current/real-core-snaps/core4_256_dens_0009.bin"

def read_chunks(f, length):
    while True:
        data = f.read(length)
        if not data: break
        yield data

loop = 0

with open(file,"rb") as f:
    for chunk in read_chunks(f, struct_len):   
        x = struct_unpack(chunk)
        low = np.minimum(x, low)
        high = np.maximum(x, high)
        loop += 1

nbins = math.ceil(math.sqrt(loop)) 

bin_edges = np.linspace(low, high, nbins + 1)
total = np.zeros(nbins, np.int64)


f = open(file,"rb")
f2 = open(file2,"rb")

for chunk1,chunk2 in zip(read_chunks(f, struct_len),read_chunks(f2, struct_len)):
    subtotal,e = np.histogram(struct_unpack(chunk1),bins=bin_edges,weights=struct_unpack(chunk2))
    total = np.add(total,subtotal,out=total,casting="unsafe")

plt.hist(bin_edges[:-1], bins=bin_edges, weights=total)
plt.savefig('hist-veldens.svg')
```

but the histogram produced is ridiculous (see below). What am I doing wrong?[image]

The data files are located at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhia2CGzl_aRX9Q9Ng61W-4XJGQe1OCV/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CrhQjyG2axSFgK9LGytELbxjy3Ndon1S/view?usp=sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that `total = np.zeros(nbins, np.int64)` is assigning an integer type to each of the elements of the array `total`. Given that `subtotal` does not contain the count number in a weighted histogram but a float-type, total should also be of type `float`.